# PostgreSQL text search with an index within a Jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, trigram

Given the following dataset:

```
-- Create random table
CREATE TABLE sample (
    id serial primary key,
    content jsonb
);

-- Insert sample rows
INSERT INTO sample (content)
VALUES 
    ('{"text": ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","consectetur adipiscing elit","sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt","ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"]}'), 
    ('{"text": ["Ut enim ad minim veniam","quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris","nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat","Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit","voluptate velit esse cillum dolore"]}'), 
    ('{"text": ["eu fugiat nulla pariatur","Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat","non proident, sunt in culpa qui","officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"]}')
;
```

`content` is a JSONB column that contains a key `text` which is a Json array of texts.

I would like to be able to search with `ILIKE` or a similar function within this text using an index.

Functionally this works and this is what I would like to do:

```
WITH ctr AS (
    SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements_text((content->>'text')::jsonb) as mytext
    FROM sample
)
SELECT id
FROM ctr
WHERE mytext ILIKE '%qui%';

 id 
----
  2
  2
  3
(3 rows)
```

Is there a solution to have the same output using an index? I am looking to query a very large dataset.

It looks like it's not possible to use a trigram index (`ERROR:  operator class "gist_trgm_ops" does not accept data type jsonb`)

Comment: Normalize your data, then you can index it properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions

```
create index idx_name on sample ((content->>'text'));

select sample.*
from sample
where content->>'text' ~ ' qui';

select sample.* 
from sample, jsonb_array_elements_text(content->'text') many(elem)
where elem ~ ' qui';
```

Besides, from Postgresql version 12+ you can use the "like_regex" to search in your JSONB column.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Check out [Selecting for a Jsonb array contains regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204467/selecting-for-a-jsonb-array-contains-regex-match) and [How to create index on json field in Postgres 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807030/how-to-create-index-on-json-field-in-postgres-9-3)